# Ubuntu 22.04 Kubernetes setup - failed to pull image

Tags: apt, software-installation, 22.04, proxy, kubernetes

I'm trying to install a Kubernetes test in my lab environment.
I'm behind a proxy which is configured for curl, apt and wget
But there is a special certificate used from forcepoint.
All ssl connections will pass through via forcepoint certificate.
I have already installed this forcepoint certificate to the root ca.

I tried to install kubernetes as described in
https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-kubernetes-on-ubuntu

I got stuck at step 10.

10. Finally, initialize the cluster by typing `sudo kubeadm init --control-plane-endpoint=master-node --upload-certs`

Here I got a connection problem with ImagePull.

To specify this a little bit more, I tried just pull the images before the rest with `sudo kubeadm pull image` I got this error message:

```
W0125 14:11:00.320619   32932 version.go:104] could not fetch a Kubernetes version from the internet: unable to get URL "https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable-1.txt": Get "https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable-1.txt": dial tcp 34.107.204.206:443: connect: connection refused
W0125 14:11:00.320751   32932 version.go:105] falling back to the local client version: v1.28.2failed to pull image "registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.28.2": output: E0125 14:11:00.598053   32975 remote_image.go:171] "PullImage from image service failed" err="rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image \"registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.28.2\": failed to resolve reference \"registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.28.2\": failed to do request: Head \"https://registry.k8s.io/v2/kube-apiserver/manifests/v1.28.2\": dial tcp 34.96.108.209:443: connect: connection refused" image="registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.28.2"
time="2024-01-25T14:11:00Z" level=fatal msg="pulling image: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image \"registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.28.2\": failed to resolve reference \"registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.28.2\": failed to do request: Head \"https://registry.k8s.io/v2/kube-apiserver/manifests/v1.28.2\": dial tcp 34.96.108.209:443: connect: connection refused"
error: exit status 1
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher
```

If I try e.g. to access https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable-1.txt via wget everything works fine.

```
wget https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable-1.txt
--2024-01-25 14:11:59--  https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable-1.txt
Connecting to 172.25.82.137:81... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://cdn.dl.k8s.io/release/stable-1.txt [following]
--2024-01-25 14:12:00--  https://cdn.dl.k8s.io/release/stable-1.txt
Connecting to 172.25.82.137:81... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 7 [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘stable-1.txt’

stable-1.txt  
100% [====================================================================>]  
7 --.-KB/s in 0s
2024-01-25 14:12:01 (205 KB/s) - ‘stable-1.txt’ saved [7/7]
```

Do you have any idea where the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing proxy settings for kubeadm i would try setting proxy in the bash:

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:port
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:port
export NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1,.example.com
```

you may need to restart containerd services

```
 systemctl restart containerd.service
```